# PHP mysqli_query doesn't return value when using a > or < symbol

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple PHP site that runs queries against a MySQL database.  When I run the following query directly in PHPMyAdmin it returns results just fine but when I run it from the PHP script it doesn't return any values.

```
SELECT film_id FROM film WHERE length > 48
```

I can run the query through my site using a `BETWEEN` function, `LIKE` function, `EQUALS` function, etc... but it won't return results when using `<` or `>`.

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Comment: Show sample data and table description please.

Comment: " but when I run it from the PHP script" ... then show us the code of your PHP script :)

Comment: First thing to note is that the database you are using is mysql. PHPMyAdmin is a web interface to mysql. It's a client, not a database.

Comment: Did you connected to db?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. You can check out the website that I built here: http://xantie.webutu.com/sql/sql.php.

Comment: what is the data in `length`?